# Why isn't my text files showing on git's preview?

Tags: text, github

`https://github.com/Doboy/Ti-83-Math-Tools/blob/master/triangle/TRIANGLE.txt`

As you can see when I go to the page above, the preview only shows one line. While if you click view raw there are much more lines. What is wrong?

Comment: reported, vote to close this.

Comment: The URL is a 404, so we can't "see when I go to the page above"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with GitHub [that you should report to them](https://github.com/contact).